# Creating Your Own Matrix Class

Tags: c++

I am creating my own Matrix class. I wrote a copy constructor, but it works correctly only for primitive classes (namely, memory allocation for data). How can the constructor be rewritten (it is possible to overload the new operator) so that it works correctly not only for primitive data types, but also for complex structures (for example, complex classes).

Class fields:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T *data = nullptr;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
```

Copy constructor:

```
Matrix(const Matrix &other) : data(new T[other.rows * other.cols]), rows(other.rows), cols(other.cols)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
            {
                data[i] = other.data[i];
            }
        }
```

It is forbidden to use STL containers, all memory management is manually

Destructor

```
 ~Matrix() {
     rows = 0;
     cols = 0;
     delete[] data;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply rely on `std::vector`? That would come with all that for free – including moving and assignment as well...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify - it is forbidden to use STL containers, all memory management is manual

Comment: Why does this one not work for classes?

Comment: @user253751 Non-default-constructable ones *do* fail due to the `new T[...]`...

Comment: Did they teach you a way to make an array of classes without calling the default constructors? It's possible, but not easy

Comment: Important:  Search the internet for "C++ FAQ Matrix".  There are some important concepts that most people overlook.

Comment: I tried googling and couldn't find any information that I have a question about. Can you send a link if you have one

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко -- *it is forbidden to use STL containers* -- That doesn't mean you can't see *how* those containers are able to do what you're trying to do.  Honestly, all the answers you're looking for just requires into looking to see how things are already done.

Comment: @Aconcagua Not for free, you'd waste two pointers worth of memory for the vector size an capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make the memory management automatic:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix() { }
    T * operator[](std::size_t x) {
        return data[x];
    }
private:
    T data[rows][cols]{};
};
```

But if you must use dynamic memory allocations:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
class Matrix {
private:
    T *data{new T[rows * cols]};
public:
    Matrix() { }
    ~Matrix() {
        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr; // crash on use after free
    }
    template<typename U>
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<U>> list) 
    : data (static_cast<T*>(operator new[](sizeof(T) * rows * cols, static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(T))))) {
        std::size_t i = 0;
        for (auto &lst : list) {
            std::size_t j = 0;
            for (auto &t : lst) {
                std::construct_at<T>(&(*this)[i][j], std::forward<const U>(t));
                ++j;
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }
    Matrix(const Matrix &other) {
        *this = other;
    }
    Matrix(T &&other) : data(other.data) {
        other.data = nullptr;
    }
    Matrix & operator=(const Matrix &other) {
        if constexpr (std::is_aggregate_v<T>) {
            memcpy(data, other.data, sizeof(T) * rows * cols);
        } else {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                    (*this)[i][j] = other[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Matrix operator=(Matrix &&other) {
        swap(data, other.data);
        return *this;
    }
    const T * operator[](std::size_t x) const {
        return &data[x * cols];
    }
    T * operator[](std::size_t x) {
        return &data[x * cols];
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Matrix<int, 2, 2> a{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};
    Matrix<int, 2, 2> b{a};
    std::cout << b[0][0] << " " << b[0][1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << b[1][0] << " " << b[1][1] << std::endl;
}
```

Note: This is a column Matrix. If you want a Row matrix you have to swap indexes around.

Comment: But what if we have a single pointer, we can access the fields (*this)[i][j], and not just (*this)[i]

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко What are you talking about? The second Matrix has a single pointer and `(*this)[i]` accesses a column and `(*this)[i][j]` a single field.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and a small question, why do we need to have two overloads of the operator [], constant and not, why not leave one?

Comment: Because one only works on `const Matrix` and the other on `Matrix` without const. `Matrix & operator=(const Matrix &other)` needs the const one. `m[0][0] = 42;` needs the not const one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your try to allocate memory for the objects:

```
: data(new T[other.rows * other.cols])
```

This default-constructs new objects of type `T` right away, to which you later on assign values. However it relies on the objects being default constructable, if they aren't, it cannot compile. So you will need to allocate memory explicitly, create the objects via *placement new* and later on destroy them explicitly alike.

Just a minimalistic demo – you'll need to place the right things at the right places within your constructors and destructor:

```
template<typename T>
void demo(size_t n, T t[])
{
    auto c = static_cast<T*>
    (
        operator new[]
        (
            n * sizeof(T), static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(T))
        )
    );

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // placement new
        new (c + i) T(t[i]);
    }

    for(size_t i = n; i--; )
    {
        // explicitly call destructor
        c[i].~C();
    }
    operator delete[](c);
}
```

Just the very basics – note that this doesn't consider exceptions occurring during construction/destruction, you'll need appropriate handling for as well.

Comment: Destructors must be called in the reverse order. Also there's exception-safety...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed... Though suppose for the very basics it should suffice, I'll just leave a note for the exceptions.

Comment: Sorry, I honestly don't understand yet how I can reproduce this on my data(new T[rows * cols]). I see this for the first time, so it's very hard to understand, now I'll add my destructor to the question (it's as simple as possible)

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко What they're proposing is to remoe `new T` completely. Instead do `operator new[]` followed by placement-new.

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко Indeed: No `new T[...]` any more! `operator new` is called implicitly when you have a `new` expression and allocates the memory required for the type. Now we do that *explicitly*, thus get totally uninitialised memory. Then there's an alternative form of a new-expression additionally receiving an address in form of a pointer. This form uses the memory provided by this pointer instead of allocating some on its own, and constructs the object there. About placement-new see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new).

Comment: Alternatively to calling `operator new` we could have `malloc`ed memory. This doesn't, though, offer a way to specify alignment for overaligned types – which the operator-new variant does.